# Web2 to Web3 on Solana

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, token

I have a member website built on WordPress where members can post content (forums, posts, jobs, articles,...). I want to turn it into web3, where members can earn tokens for posting content. I want to build it on Solana network. Where do I start and what do I need to do?
Thanks.

Comment: This question lacks focus. You should check out the other answers here about making a token and transferring tokens.